# What is the scientific name of this lovely orange black flying beetle?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

Found on Rangoon creeper (*Combretum indicum*)

[image: My phone]

[image: one more]

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Thanks captured with my phone in my terrace garden

Comment: For the beard of Zeus, was this photo taken with a phone? Incredible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [blister beetle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blister_beetle) from the species [*Mylabris pustulata*](http://eol.org/pages/3282959/overview).

Here is another photo for comparison:

[image]

<sup>Source: http://www.knowyourinsects.org/Coleoptera1.html</sup>

And, just for fun, the specimen in my link and yours, side by side:

[image]

It's worth mentioning that *Mylabris* has been confused with the Genus *Hycleus*, and the synonymy is [complex](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00222930110062318).